# Disabling jmx SSL

Tags: java, oracle, jmx

I am trying to set the following system property when I start the Java VM.
I am following this oracle guide in order to set java jmx properties [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html).
This is the command line that I tried to execute in cmd :

*java -D com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false*.

But I am getting this error:
*impossible to find or load pricipal class com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl*

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space between -D and parameter key.

Correct value is: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

Comment: I am using windows cmd.
I tried also this, but I am getting the syntax help showing the java command line options.

Comment: What is the full command you are executing? There has to be more than just "java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

Comment: This is the full command : java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

Comment: And what do you expect it should do? There is no class to execute nor classpath definition in that command.

Comment: Even if I try like this: java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false.    I am getting the same result.